# How to copy the page with current date?

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I would like to copy some page with the current date.

Example myPage.html -> myPage_2013-08-15_13:36.html

The following code copies the page but without date. It is because of such signs (-, :,....). How can you overcome this?

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" );
String testDate= df.format(date);

pageManager.copy(pathOfMyPage, pathOfMyPage+"-"+testDate, "", true, false);
```

Comment: What is the value of `pathOfMyPage+"-"+testDate`?

Comment: Please correct your posted code - there are syntax errors such as the closing bracket after pathOfMyPage

Comment: It looks like an extra parenthesis before the first comma.

Comment: None of the function declarations of `copy()` contain a `String` as first parameter. Please correct that. I think that would be your problem.

Comment: Well - what is the declaration of pageManager.copy?

Comment: Note, in the Windows FS the character ':' is illegal in a file name, for Windows you'll need to replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Page myPage = ... // the Page object

Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("_yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm");
String newName = myPage.getName() + df.format(date);

pageManager.copy(myPage, newName, null, true, false);
```

NOTE:
As I am not 100% sure of what `.getName()` actually returns, it is possible that you will need to *cut off* any file name extention (.html ?) it may return and then tag it back on for the call to `.copy(...)`.